# Flutter Android Studio unit tests - need to delete run/debug config to pick up changed code

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, flutter

In Android Studio, running unit tests for a Flutter project, after having run a unit test once, in order **for code changes to be picked up, I need to delete the run / debug config** before re-running the unit test.

Why?

Is there a unit test cache build setting I can disable so I don't need to delete the config prior to re-running the test? I don't need to do this for re-running unit tests in IDEA when working on a pure Dart project.

I delete the run/debug config in Android Studio Run > Edit Configurations... > Flutter Test > [delete any configs for unit tests I want to re-run].

For example, the below, I would delete any unit tests (which I mostly run individually) from underneath the Flutter Test section of this Run/Debug Configurations window in Android Studio.

[image: Delete unit test run/debug config]